# How can I tell when HD Voice is being used in a phone call?

Tags: iphone

The iPhone 5 supports a wideband audio protocol for phone calls dubbed HD Voice that is supposed to improve the clarity of phone calls when it's used. Not all providers support it, but I've verified that my provider, Telus, does.

How can I tell when HD Voice is in use during a call? Is there a visual indicator in the phone app?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, iPhone5 dont have HD voice indicator, i realised this when calling my dad with his Z10, he said there is HD Voice title on his Z10 answer button but there is no particular hd voice symbol or what so ever on my i5. Well, the voice quality with hd voice is just so clear and different, you should know whether hd voice is on or not just by voice quality.